# Usage of terms prior and posterior in probability

Tags: terminology, probability

Probability function is of two types in general. They are unconditional probability and conditional probability.

But the terms prior probability and posterior probability are used in place of unconditional probability and conditional probability respectively.

In which year do the usage of terms prior and posterior started in probability?

Comment: [Jeff Miller's site](http://jeff560.tripod.com/p.html) states that Jakob Burnoulli was the first to used these terms in the context of deriving probabilities, but the terms did not become standard until after Laplace's *Théorie Analytique des Probabilités*  of (1812)

Comment: "Prior" and "posterior" are not synonymous with "unconditional" and "conditional". The former reflect empirical interpretations, the latter only the method of calculation in a model.